# sparklyr method not working - unable to find an inherited method for function ‘count’ for signature ‘"tbl_spark"’

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm trying to use sparklyr from RStudio server. Spark is installed in a cluster and I use yarn to connect. Conection works correctly but when I try a simple example as get from documentation I get error:

"Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘count’ for signature ‘"tbl_spark"’

This is my simple code:

```
> library(sparklyr)
> library(dplyr)
> sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn")
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

> iris_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc = sc, x = iris, overwrite = T)
[1] "iris"
> iris_tbl %>% count
  Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘count’ for signature ‘"tbl_spark"’
```

I cannot fiture what is wrong in so simple example. +

Copy below my sessionInfo

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               C_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] sparklyr_0.8.1-9001 devtools_1.13.5     nycflights13_0.2.2      rJava_0.9-9         SparkR_2.1.0        slam_0.1-42        
 [7] stringi_1.1.6       dplyr_0.7.4         servr_0.8           topicmodels_0.2-7   tm_0.7-3            NLP_0.1-11         
[13] LDAvis_0.3.2       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_0.2.4  modeltools_0.2-21 purrr_0.2.4       reshape2_1.4.3    lattice_0.20-35   htmltools_0.3.6   stats4_3.4.3     
 [8] yaml_2.1.19       base64enc_0.1-3   utf8_1.1.3        rlang_0.2.0       pillar_1.2.1      foreign_0.8-69    glue_1.2.0       
[15] withr_2.1.2       DBI_1.0.0         rappdirs_0.3.1    dbplyr_1.2.1      bindrcpp_0.2      bindr_0.1.1       plyr_1.8.4       
[22] stringr_1.2.0     memoise_1.1.0     psych_1.8.4       httpuv_1.3.6.2    parallel_3.4.3    curl_3.2          broom_0.4.4      
[29] Rcpp_0.12.15      readr_1.1.1       xtable_1.8-2      openssl_1.0.1     backports_1.1.2   jsonlite_1.5      config_0.3       
[36] mime_0.5          mnormt_1.5-5      hms_0.4.2         digest_0.6.15     shiny_1.0.5       rprojroot_1.3-2   grid_3.4.3       
[43] cli_1.0.0         tools_3.4.3       magrittr_1.5      lazyeval_0.2.1    tibble_1.4.2      crayon_1.3.4      tidyr_0.8.0      
[50] pkgconfig_2.0.1   xml2_1.2.0        assertthat_0.2.0  httr_1.3.1        rstudioapi_0.7    R6_2.2.2          git2r_0.21.0     
[57] nlme_3.1-131      compiler_3.4.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using wrong function. `count` is a function which requires column and:

> wrapper for summarise that will either
>        call ‘n()’ or ‘sum(n)’ depending on whether you're tallying for
>        the first time, or re-tallying. ‘count()’ is similar but calls
>        ‘group_by()’ before and ‘ungroup()’ after

so

```
df %>% count(x)
```

is the same as

```
df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% ungroup()
```

To count records use `summarise`:

```
iris_tbl %>% summarise(n = n())
```

or

```
iris_tbl %>% spark_dataframe() %>% invoke("count")
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much for the explanation. Obviusly the example I took was wrong.